# Symfony2 Can't load form type class

Tags: symfony

I generates class name dependent of request parameters in url. For example:
...some_url...?category_id=3

ID 3 it is entity class: AdFlat
For using form type, I use form class AdFlatType.

In controller:

```
    public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        $categoryId = $request->get('category_id');

        if ($categoryId) {
            $category = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdBundle:AdCategory')->find($categoryId);

            if (null === $category) {
                return $this->renderError('You cannot create Ad for this category');
            }

            if (null === $category->getEntity()) {
                return $this->renderError('You cannot create Ad for category ' . $category->getTitle());
            }

            $entityName = $category->getEntity();
            $formTypeName = $entityName . 'Type';

            $formType = new $formTypeName();
            $entity = new $entityName();
        }
}
```

In USE section:

```
use AdBundle\Form\Type\AdFlatType;
```

But anyway I receive error:

> Attempted to load class "AdFlatType" from the global namespace. Did
>   you forget a "use" statement?

What the trouble?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$category->getEntity()` should return fully qualified class name, not just `AdFlat` but `AdBundle\Form\Type\AdFlat`.

Comment: Dynamicly created class throught `new AdBundle\Form\Type\AdFlatType()` also not working. I get same error, but for AdBundle\Form\Type\AdFlatType class.

Comment: Oh, sorry, your answer is right. I put some mistakes. Thanks!